# Time ordering, interaction Lagrangian calculation, QED

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

I am trying to compute

$$ \langle 0| \,  T\left\{\phi^\dagger(x_1) \phi(x_2) \exp \left[i \! \int{L_1(x) \, \mathrm{d}x} \right] \right\}|0 \rangle $$

for

$$ L_1(x) = -ieA_{\mu}[\phi^*(\partial_\mu \phi ) - (\partial_\mu \phi^*)\phi]. $$

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi @askalot. Is this from some textbook/reference/journal/online resource? Consider adding references in order to receive useful and focused answers.

Comment: I am trying to find an expression including the propagators, wick's theorem, and then calculate the Feynman diagrams in position space.
 The solution should include terms of up to $ e^2 $   order.
 I am not sure if the Lagrangian $ L^1(x) $  is the interaction Lagrangian, so that I should use it as it is in the integral, or if I should extract an interaction Lagrangian out of it.
 I also have to tell you that I am not expected to calculate complex integrals in every detail, or be occupied with infinities.

Comment: Hi Qmechanic, No it is not from some textbook/reference/journal/online resource. Our lecturer posted it during a QFT lesson.